# How to Text wrap and add ... at the end

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-3.0

Lets say you have this text

"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Maecenas porttitor congue massa. Fusce posuere, magna sed pulvinar ultricies, purus lectus malesuada libero, sit amet commodo magna eros quis urna."

put in a textblock with TextWrapping="Wrap", the textblock only supports 2 lines, so how do I add the usual "..." at the end of the text so as to say there is more to read

Comment: are you only allowing 2 lines in the textblock?  it's certainly not limited to only two lines by default

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not trivial to answer for use in SilverLight because you cannot use native Win32 methods (of which some methods support ellipsis). There are a few resources on the Net, which basically come down to one of two approaches:

1. Do-it-yourself calculation, here's a ready made class, you may need to alter it a bit to work with more then one line: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/AutoEllipsis.aspx
2. Use `TextRenderer.DrawText`, not sure if that's available or useful in your scenario: http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/how-to-auto-ellipse-text-in-csharp

Comment: TextRenderer isn't available in Silverlight.

Answer (score 0):

This question has been correctly answered here: [How do I truncate a string with an ellipsis in a Silverlight TextBlock?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7327704/how-do-i-truncate-a-string-with-an-ellipsis-in-a-silverlight-textblock)

Silverlight 4 supports the TextTrimming property for TextBlock controls.

```
<TextBlock TextTrimming="WordEllipsis"/>
```