# How do I truncate a string with an ellipsis in a Silverlight TextBlock?

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

If I display a string too long for a TextBlock it just appears to keep writing past the edge of the TextBlock.  I'd rather it use the common technique of adding an ellipsis ("...") if the text is not going to fit in the space provided.  How should I go about doing this in Silverlight?

The references I've found all use the TextRenderer class which is not available in Silverlight

Comment: I found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565953/how-to-text-wrap-and-add-at-the-end which asks the same question, but both examples given in the accepted answer use TextRenderer, so they are not actually applicable for Silverlight.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You didn't say which Silverlight version this is. Assuming Silverlight 4, it's baked into TextBlock via the [TextTrimming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.texttrimming%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) property.

```
<TextBlock TextTrimming="WordEllipsis"/>
```

The only thing you have to do is make sure your TextBlock's width is properly restricted and you use [NoWrap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.textwrapping%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) for [TextWrapping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.textwrapping%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

Set the TextTrimming property to WordEllipsis.

```
<TextBlock Text="My long text" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis"/>
```